# nested do and if statements miss plots

Tags: gnuplot

I am using

> G N U P L O T
>       Version 4.6 patchlevel 4    last modified 2013-10-02
>       Build System: Linux x86_64

which I want to use to plot data from a file that is roughly set up like this

> 0.0  a1  b1
>   0.0  a2  b2
>   ...
>   0.1  a1  b1*
>   0.1  a2  b2*
>   ...

for each unique value in the first column I want to plot b over a. To do this I have created a do loop which contains conditional plotting

> do for [t=0:34] {
>   print 0.2000*t
>   plot 'twopi5101/profile.dat' u ($1==0.2000*t ? ($3-7.5) : 1/0):8 notitle w l lt 1 lc 1, \
>    'twopi5101/profile.dat' u ($1==0.2000*t ? ($3-7.5) : 1/0):9 notitle w l lt 1 lc 2
>   }

unfortunately this loop (and similar loops for other files) will consistently miss some plots

> 0.0
>   0.2
>   0.4
>   0.6
>         warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
>         warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
>   more> ;print 0.2000*t;plot 'twopi5101/profile.dat' u ($1==0.2000*t ? ($3-7.5) : 1/0):8 notitle w l lt 1 lc 1,      'twopi5101/profile.dat' u ($1==0.2000*t ? ($3-7.5) : 1/0):9 notitle w l lt 1 lc 2;
>                                                                                                                                                                                                       ^
>         x range is invalid

however, if I manually input the 0.6 there is no problem at all

> gnuplot> plot 'twopi5101/profile.dat' u ($1==0.6 ? ($3-7.5) : 1/0):8 notitle w l lt 1 lc 1, \
>       'twopi5101/profile.dat' u ($1==0.6 ? ($3-7.5) : 1/0):9 notitle w l lt 1 lc 2
>   gnuplot>

There seems to be no logical explanation for why this should happen, or even a pattern for points missed.
of the interval [0.0:6.0] gnuplot skipped:
0.6,1.2,1.4,2.4,2.8,3.4,3.8,4.6,4.8,5.6,5.8
and it does so consistently every time I run the loop, even if I run it over just part of that interval (e.g. running from 0.6 to 2.0 will again skil 0.6,1.2 and 1.4).

I've run into the same behavior in a number of other cases for larger intervals/more plots. I have no idea what would even cause something like this or if there is some error in my formatting of the loop to explain it.
(terminals I use are either 'wxt' or postscript enhanced)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because testing floating point values on equality is generally not a good idea. Let's consider for example:

```
gnuplot> print 0.6==0.6
1
gnuplot> print 0.6==3*0.2
0
```

This is a consequence of the fact that numbers like `0.2` are not represented exactly.

I would suggest to first convert the first column in your data to an integer value by, e.g.,

```
floor(($1 + 0.05)*10)
```

Here it is assumed that the column in question contains only multiples of `0.1`. The factor `0.05` is present to ensure that possible inaccurate input such as or example `0.1000001` or `0.0999999` gets converted to `1`.

This converted value can be then used in the filtering within the `plot` command, e.g.,

```
plot 'twopi5101/profile.dat' u (floor(($1+0.05)*10)==2*t?($3-7.5):1/0):8
```

Alternatively, one could replace the condition `$1==0.2000*t` with something like `abs($1 - 0.2000*t)<5E-2`